# RavenDB querying with object that doesn't have Id property

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I am using an class to store data in RavenDb but I cannot change the structure of the class to include the **"Id"** property.  I'd like to use the Id property to retrieve a document later.  How can I do this?

I have tried using a base class as follows:

```
class Customer : CustomerRecord
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
   public string State { get; set; }
   public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

where CustomerRecord would contain the **"Id"** property like this:

```
class CustomerRecord
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then we want to be able to run something like the code below that queries the **"Customer"** documents but returns a **"CustomerRecord"** format including the Id:

```
using (var session = _docStore.OpenSession())
{
   var customer = session.Query<Customer>()
            .ToList<CustomerRecord>();
}
```

The code above doesn't work because a linq query needs to have the Query type and the ToList type be the same.  Can anyone help with a solution to returning the base class?

I am very new to RavenDB so forgive me if this is an obvious question.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are your particular problem is and why dont you just select IDs like this:

```
session.Query<Customer>().Select(c=> c.Id).ToList()
```

Or maybe

```
session.Query<Customer>().ToList().Cast<CustomerRecord>()
```

Or maybe what you are looking for is multi-map index:
http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/polymorphism

Comment: I need to return the whole record so maybe your second example with the Cast() is what I need. I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that RavenDB will return the first 128 documents only, see http://ravendb.net/docs/intro/safe-by-default

Answer (score 0):

You say you "cannot change the structure of the class to include the `Id` property" but yet you *can* apparently modify the base class ... that changes the structure of the class. These two pieces of information don't seem to make sense together. Could you clarify?

That said, it is not a really great idea to use classes you don't control as your model classes in RavenDB. This can only lead to heartache if they would get changed behind your back. In a schemaless document database, those classes ARE your schema. You wouldn't just cede control of your SQL schema to a third party!

Regarding the suggestion for using `.Cast<T>()` from another answer, this happens client side and isn't the best, as that happens all client side. RavenDB contains two methods for doing server-side projections, [`.OfType<T>()`](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/results-transformation/of-type) and [`ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<T>`](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/results-transformation/project-from-index-fields-into), that differ slightly in how they work.

`.OfType<T>()` allows you to change to a radically different type that just happens to have some of the same properties. A benefit is the server will only send down the properties you need to hydrate that type, for example, to populate a view model class that need not inherit or relate to the model class.

`.ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<T>()` does the same thing but takes those values directly from the stored values in Lucene (the backing storage & search capability behind RavenDB indexes) without regard to what is in the model document itself.

Check the linked documentation pages for more specifics, although I *think* in your situation you'll probably be looking for `.OfType<T>()`.

Comment: David, your inital points are valid however I can't really explain the reasons without divulging information that I can't share.  I do know that the structure of data is controlled internally and are not subject to change as they would be with a third party.  Thanks for the suggestions on OfType and ProjectFromIndexFieldInto. I will be trying these very soon.